# Covering Space of $\mathbb{C}-\{a,b\}$ via Multivalued Function

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-numbers, group-actions, covering-spaces, multivalued-functions

Consider the multivalued complex function $f(z)= \sqrt{z-a}+\sqrt{z-b}$, where $a\neq b$, defined in the domain $U=\mathbb{C}-\{a,b\}$. The graph $W$ of $f$ defines a regular covering space $W \rightarrow U$ with discrete fiber $F$.

(a) How many sheets does this covering have?

(b) If $w_a$ is a small loop about $a$ and not containing $b$ in its interior and similarly  $w_b$ is a small loop about $b$ and not containing $a$ in its interior, determine the action of $w_a$ and $w_b$ on the fiber $F$.

(c) There exists a group $G$ so that $W/G$ is homeomorphic.

Attempt:

(a) Since $U$ is connected and we are given that this is a covering we know that the cardinality of the fiber is constant over $U$. So wlog, assume $a\neq 0, b\neq 0$. Then the fiber at 0, $F_0$, is $\{f(0)\}=\{\sqrt{-a}+\sqrt{-b}, a\neq b\}=\{\pm z_a \mp z_b\}$. Since $a,b$ are distinct this has $4$ elements, so we have a $4-$ fold covering.

(b) I'm not sure about this one. I see that $U$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$v $ S^1$, but don't really know how to use this. I am guessing the loops $w_a$, $w_b$ would take the point $+z_a - z_b$ to $-z_a - z_b$ and $+z_a + z_b$, but this is just a hunch.

(c) Don't really know, but am guessing $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 $?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you meant to say in (b), but otherwise everything looks correct to me. Note that if you just take the regular square root function in $\mathbb C$ and travel full circle around the origin, the value of the square root is negated. If you just travel within some arc between two angles pointing out of the origin, though, then the value is unchanged upon returning to the same parameter. Use this knowledge to figure out exactly what the action is in part (b).

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Okay, so a loop around $a$, $w_a$ will negate the $z_a$ term and similarly for $w_b$. Each of these loops is also just movement within an arc wrt the other point, so it does not affect the other term. So this cover is connected then? And what is the image of $f$? I want to say $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$

Comment: nvm, $0 $ is definitely in image... $f((a-bi)/(1-i))$